# hbase - If the rowkey is designed very long(eg 200 letter ),but it is helpful for scan and filter. is there any harmful for the long rowkey design?

Tags: hadoop, hbase

If the rowkey is designed very long(eg 200 letter ),but it is helpful for scan and filter. is there harmful for the long rowkey design?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would say - **don't make rowkeys too long**. Even though, long rowkeys may seem tempting for scanning based on some filters , it will take up more heap space than warranted. 
`Store files in hbase are LSM trees. To speed up random access within the store files , an index is stored for Data Block and Meta Block , which contain  first key for each block along with other information. When added up for lots of blocks, it may take up big chunk of RAM.`
Check the total size of store file index for hfiles and see if this is problemous  in your case or not.
 If unavoidable then 
some solutions may be - increase the block size and enable compression.
Also look at https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/HBASE-3551 for some interesting read.

Comment: So you mean，The first row key of each data block will be index that existing in RAM,so the long rowkey will take up big chunk of RAM. that is the potential harm.  But the length of row key(200 letters) should be ok when the block size is 64k by default?   anyway thank you!

Comment: yeah..it should be ok.. btw, its a trial and error method. And ,even if, in future if you get into this problem, you can increase block size at that time.

Answer (score 0):

There're two choices for rowkey design,`tall-narrow` and `flat-wide`. According to your business you can choose one of them. There's no harm for the long rowkey desing.